# Find partial match of full-string and column value (partial string) using active record method

Tags: sql, mysql, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Here I have a list of full-string that I need to find its match from the name column and return their respective id no. from the database (ActiveRecord).

["Superior Suite","Triple Family Room",....]

DB

```
Id   |    Name
1    |    Single
2    |    Double
3    |    Triple
4    |    Suite
```

Expected Result
"Superior Suite" -> Id: 4 (Partial Match with Suite)
"Triple Family Room" -> Id: 3 (Partial Match with Triple)

I managed to get the expected result using the sql query below,

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE 'Superior Suite' LIKE CONCAT ('%', Name, '%');
```

however, I wanted to know how I can write using ActiveRecord methods.
Something like this...

```
db.select('id').where("Superior Suite" LIKE "%Name%")
```

or if you know any other method, please let me know.

Appreciated your helps!

Answer (score 1):

I would say you can go with that:

```
db.where("name LIKE ?", "%Superior Suite%").pluck(:id)
```

And here are some good examples how you can use these statements as well:
[Query](https://gorm.io/docs/query.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried your answer but unfortunately it only works for full-match cases. I'm looking for answer where I can get id from records from partial match of 'Name' column is contained in the search keyword. keyword: 'Superior Suite' -> match with Name Column's 'suite' and return the Id: '4' .